# Does DB2 LUW v10.5 Support Windows Authentication and How is it Set?

Tags: db2, authentication, db2-luw

We have a DB2 LUW v10.5 FP1 Express Edition. Can someone please confirm that this database supports Windows Authentication over the network (and if so, kindly provide some steps to do it) or does it only support Windows Authentication on the Server host?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is it about skipping database authentication for successfully authenticated Windows AD users? If so, you may want to consider [enabling Kerberos authentication](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0011990.html)

Answer (score 1):

DB2 supports various authentication models, special models for Microsoft Windows included. I recommend starting at [DB2 and Windows Security](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005897.html) in the DB2 Knowledge Center for your options and details.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will check it out and come back here for feedback.